# How do I trigger a rails controller action on Javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am building a Rails application and I need to trigger a Update action from one of my controller on a JS event.

My controller's action currently looks something like that:

```
  def update
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
    authorize @subscription
    @subscription.update(subscription_params)
    redirect_to tournament_subscriptions_path(@subscription.tournament)
  end
```

What I would like to do is to trigger that action on a JS event : say when the current user select a new value in a select box. 
I believe this is done with an Ajax post method ? But As I am new to programming I have no idea of how to implement it...

I guess there's some JS that looks like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#subscription-status").change(function(){
    $.post(?????);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure how what route leads to that action (you haven't provided this information, so we cannot help here) then what URL matches that route, and then access that URL (with the appropriate http method) via AJAX.

If the route is `posts#update` and it's accessed by a `PUT` to `/posts/:id`, you would do something like:

```
$.post("/posts/" + id, { _method: 'put' });
```

Comment: Ty for info @meagar, sorry for any confusion!

Comment: @meagar Indeed it is an update action : my rake routes gives me to possible routes :   
PATCH    /tournaments/:tournament_id/subscriptions/:id(.:format)           subscriptions#update
 PUT      /tournaments/:tournament_id/subscriptions/:id(.:format)           subscriptions#update

Another problem is that these routes are double nested ( tournament_id + id !!)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#subscription-status").change(function(){ 
    $.ajax({url: "subscription-status", type: "POST"}
```

You will the have to add in `config/routes.rb`:

```
post '/subscription-status', to: 'controller-name#update'
```

The `$.ajax` call also takes other options:

```
dataType: "json",
data: { file_name: $(this).text() }, // This goes to Controller in params hash, i.e. params[:file_name]
complete: function() {},
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {},
error: function() { alert("Ajax error!") }
```

Comment: that looks pretty good but my update url has two ids in it :
PATCH    /tournaments/:tournament_id/subscriptions/:id(.:format)           subscriptions#update

so I should writte somthing like:

$.ajax({url: "subscription-status(tournament_id, subscription_id)", type: "POST"} ?